# Rails 4: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I have this class:

```
class SuperAppController < ApplicationController
    layout 'app'
    add_flash_types :error, :info
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    after_action :check_account!

    before_filter do
    if current_empresa != nil
     authenticate_empresa!
    else
     authenticate_user!
    end
  end


    private
    def check_account!
        if empresa_signed_in? && current_empresa.data_pagamento.blank? ||
        empresa_signed_in? && current_empresa.data_pagamento && Time.zone.now > current_empresa.data_pagamento + 1.year
           redirect_to pagamento_index_path, notice: 'Active your account' and return
        end
    end

end
```

I use the function "check_account" to see if the account of user was expired.
When the action is loaded, I'm getting this error:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

When I do before_action instead of after_action I get the same error, but the view of the error is not loaded. I get e message from browser saying: "Localhost is not working". And I can see a lot of requests logs on terminal.

Someone know why I'm geting so many redirects?

thanks!

Comment: For this `after_action` to be triggered, you must of been making a request to a specific action. Mind including this in your question? Could be that your `check_account!` should be a `before_action`. Consider an action that `render`s some view. An action can either `render` or `redirect_to` once. If your action renders, then your check tries to `redirect_to` then you run into this problem. You might want to `redirect_to` before `rendering` the action (aka `before_action`).

Comment: I tried that. When I do before_action I get the same error, but the view of the error is not loaded. I get e message from browser saying: "Localhost is not working"

Comment: Could you provide the action from `SuperAppController` that you're trying to render?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but using callbacks like that (some may say at all), make these sorts of things very hard to debug. I would remove all your callbacks (before_* and after_*) and handle these things directly in the action you're hitting. Then things will be much clearer.

Comment: This section of my app come from this class. So it is many other classes who have this inherit. its not just one. All sections inherit this class. Its about 12 classes who inherit this class.

Comment: I show in this controller above all actions who he have